# Javafx WebEngine load html file from jar

Tags: javafx, javafx-webengine

I am building a project and need to use WebEngine class. So I have 2 projects, `MainA` and `SecondB`. The `SecondB` project is in dependency to `MainA`, so after building it `SecondB` becomes a jar file in the `MainA` libs folder.
Now. I need to open a `abc.html` file that is under `SecondB` resources. When testing it locally it works, when building an app and deploying it on server it fails (probably because it is in `SecondB` jar file). So the code I am using is:

```
WebView browser = new WebView();
WebEngine webEngine = browser.getEngine();  
ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
String s = classLoader.getResource("subfolder/abc.html").toExternalForm();
webEngine.load(s);
```

The method `classLoader.getResource("subfolder/abc.html").toExternalForm();`returns a normal url when running the code localy and something like:

```
file:jar:C:/Something/MainA/libs/SecondB.jar!/subfolder/abc.html
```

Do you have any ideas how to load this file from a jar? I tried several options I found on SO, but without success

Comment: Put the .html file in same resources folder then create a jar file

Comment: Do you meain resources folder of the Main project?

Comment: Yes , they need to be in same folder in order to package them into jar file,as far I know

Answer (score 1):

You can create a "resources" package and copy your files to this package and for accessing your file path for example an html you can use this: `getClass().getResource("/resources/abc.html").toURI().toString()` this provides to get your files url in your created jar. Hope it is useful.

Comment: I already have a resource package in my SecondB project and that is where the file is. Or maybe you mean put it in the Main projekt under resources? I considered that, but do not like this solution to be honest.

Comment: The `/resources` subdirectory is redundant unless you want it that way. But there are usually many subdirectories inside `/resource`. So I'd recommend `...getResource("/doc/abc.html")`, etc

Answer (score 0):

To me, I did this

```
String fileloc = "/docs/help/userguide.html";
...
String fullLink = getClass().getResource(fileloc).toExternalForm();
...
```

I store the html file inside the resources folder. e.g./resources/docs/help/userguide.html

As I run the compiled jar, it has no problem being loaded up by javafx webengine.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are almost there, you can read the url via `InputStream` into `String`, and use `WebEngine.loadContent` to load the `String` content, provided you only want to display single page. If your page reference to other files (javascript/css), it will not work.

So, it is better to this, while your JavaFX app is started, you copy out the whole resource folder into your local file system, then use the `WebEngine` to load the HTML file, this should work better.